# SQL - why is this 'where' needed to remove row duplicates, when I'm already grouping?

Tags: sql, join, group-by, where-clause, duplicates

- Why, in this query, is the final 'WHERE' clause needed to limit duplicates?
- The first LEFT JOIN is linking programs to entities on a UID
- The first INNER JOIN is linking programs to a subquery that gets statistics for those programs, by linking on a UID
- The subquery (that gets the StatsForDistributorClubs subset) is doing a grouping on UID columns
- So, I would've thought that this would all be joining unique records anyway so we shouldn't get row duplicates
- So why the need to limit based on the final WHERE by ensuring the 'program' is linked to the 'entity'?

(irrelevant parts of query omitted for clarity)

```
SELECT  LmiEntity.[DisplayName]
        ,StatsForDistributorClubs.*
FROM    [Program]
LEFT JOIN
        LMIEntityProgram
ON      LMIEntityProgram.ProgramUid = Program.ProgramUid
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  e.LmiEntityUid,
            sp.ProgramUid,
            SUM(attendeecount) [Total attendance],

        FROM    LMIEntity e,
                Timetable t,
                TimetableOccurrence [to],
                ScheduledProgramOccurrence spo,
                ScheduledProgram sp
        WHERE   
                t.LicenseeUid = e.lmientityUid
        AND     [to].TimetableOccurrenceUid = spo.TimetableOccurrenceUid
        AND     sp.ScheduledProgramUid = spo.ScheduledProgramUid

        GROUP BY e.lmientityUid, sp.ProgramUid
    ) AS StatsForDistributorClubs
ON Program.ProgramUid = StatsForDistributorClubs.ProgramUid
INNER JOIN LmiEntity
ON LmiEntity.LmiEntityUid = StatsForDistributorClubs.LmiEntityUid
LEFT OUTER JOIN Region
ON Region.RegionId = LMIEntity.RegionId
WHERE (
       [Program].LicenseeUid = LmiEntity.LmiEntityUid 
       OR
       [LMIEntityProgram].LMIEntityUid = LmiEntity.LmiEntityUid 
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were grouping in your outer query, the extra criteria probably wouldn't be needed, but only your inner query is grouped.  Your LEFT JOIN to a grouped inner query can still result in multiple records being returned, for that matter any of your JOINs could be the culprit.

Without seeing sample of duplication it's hard to know where the duplicates originate from, but GROUPING on the outer query would definitely remove full duplicates, or revised JOIN criteria could take care of it.

Comment: Thanks - that's a good point and narrows down the cause.  I'll award this the answer as it's unreasonable to expect anyone to pinpoint this without access to the data, which I'm unable to provide

Answer (score 1):

You have in result set:
    SELECT  LmiEntity.[DisplayName]
        ,StatsForDistributorClubs.*

I suppose that you dublicates comes from LMIEntityProgram.

My conjecture: LMIEntityProgram - is a bridge table with both LmiEntityId an ProgramId, but you join only by   ProgramId.

If you have several LmiEntityId for single ProgramId - you must have dublicates.

And this dublicates you're filtering in WHERE:

```
 [LMIEntityProgram].LMIEntityUid = LmiEntity.LmiEntityUid
```

You can do it in JOIN:

```
 LEFT JOIN LMIEntityProgram
    ON LMIEntityProgram.ProgramUid = Program.ProgramUid
        AND [LMIEntityProgram].LMIEntityUid = LmiEntity.LmiEntityUid
```

Comment: Thanks Ingaz, however I'm linking on ProgramUID not ProgramId, so there should only be one unique 'Program' record.  This wouldn't be where the duplicates are coming from.  Thanks for the input - I've upvoted you anyway because your suggestion could easily have been the case